# MySQL data to Postgres every X time

Tags: mysql, postgresql, data-warehouse

Our team (Uni students) have a project that we are updating.

Old project team has a Live MySQL database. We want to make a archive/warehouse from it in PostgreSQL.

My question is: How can we import / copy data from MySQL DB to PostgreSQL DB after every X time (12 hours for instance) has passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to either use an ETL Tool eg Microsoft SSIS. There's plenty of open source products available too. Or you can build your own extract utility using a programming language like PHP, .Net etc.

The Kimball guys have an article on whether you should build your own or use an off the shelf product.
http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/04/should-you-use-an-etl-tool/

To schedule the load, you can use windows scheduler on Windows or cron jobs on Unix.